# CSS getting loaded but not taking affect

Tags: css

The external css I use in my jsp file works fine locally and the css *does* have effect.

However, when I run the same jsp file on my server, the external css is loaded but not applied.
If I use `type="text/css"`, there is no effect, too.

Comment: please show us your `<link>` element

Comment: How is anyone honestly supposed to answer this with the information you've provided?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that the path on the server is the same like in you local directories? - I have sometimes problems when things get included via php/... that I refer to the wrong destinations after pushing all stuff to the server.